# Change read only property of telerik grid column based on another column dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, telerik-grid

I am using telerik grid in MVC

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<CSSI.VUE.Entities.ICW>()
.Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(a => a.DRPDATA).Width(25).ClientTemplate("<#= DRPDATAtext #>").Title("manually/system");
                        columns.Bound(a => a.DATAVALUE.Width(15).Title("Amount ($)").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).ReadOnly(true).Format("{0:###,##0.00}");
                    }
```

First column is a dropdown with Yes/No value and second column is textbox with read only property to true. I want to change that if user select Yes in first column then second column textbox should not be read only, user can enter the amount manually. but if user select No in dropdown, second column textbox should be in read only mode. system will automatically take the amount from database.

Is there is any better way to get this feature, whether by JQuery or MVC. please help

I tried this with below Jquery function. but this is not working.

```
function Dropdown_onChange(e) {
var gridData = $('#elgrd').data("tGrid");
var column = gridData.columns[1];
column.readonly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add events to your grid when you initialize it. Notice the 'onChange' event

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Title("Units In Stock");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
        .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))      
)
```

then in your JS you declare the event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onChange(arg) {
        var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {

            //check for whichever column the select is supposed to be in (1 as a place holder)              
            if ($(item).parent().children().index($(item)) == 1) {
                if ($(item).children().val() == 'YES') { //provided there is only the <select> in that <td>, otherwise you would need to drill down to get at the <select>  
                    var nextColumn = $(item).next(); //get next column cell value
                    nextColumn.readonly = true;
                }
                else {
                    var nextColumn = $(item).next();
                    nextColumn.readonly = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I do not have a telerik project in front of me at the moment but something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function Dropdown_onChange(e) { 
    var val = $(e.target).val();
    $(e.target).parents('td').next('td').find('input').attr('disabled', val !== "YES");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in functions of the rad controls. Write some jQuery like this below to fire an event if the dropdown changes. Check it for your value, and use Telerik functions.

```
$('.rcbInput').on('change', function(){ if($(this).val() != 'yes'){
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.rgInput').disable();
}
});
```

These are the Telerik functions that are already written for you that come with the telerik elements:

```
   disable: function() {
      this.set_enabled(false);
      this._textBoxElement.disabled = "disabled";
      this.updateCssClass();
      this.updateClientState();
      this.raise_disable(Sys.EventArgs.Empty);
      },
   enable: function() {
      this.set_enabled(true);
      this._textBoxElement.disabled = "";
      this.updateCssClass();
      this.updateClientState();
      this.raise_enable(Sys.EventArgs.Empty);
     },
```

No need to reinvent the wheel here. The Telerik elements have 1000's of lines of JavaScript code for their elements. If you needed to do something different you can always extend the Telerik plugin.

Be sure and put the change function inside the ready function. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik's Grid fires the `edit` event whenever the user edits a data item. So you can employ it and disable the next `<td>` like so:

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#elgrd").kendoGrid({
            edit: function(e) {
                var target = $(e.container).closest("td").next();
                var isEnabled = false; // run your logic to determine the enabled state
                target.enable(isEnabled);
            }
        });
    }
);
```